# Unit Testing class with cocos2d::UserDefault - How to read from custom XML file

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, unit-testing, cocos2d-x

I have a class that stores user preferences. When the class is created it retrieves data from the UserDefault file on iOS using the cocos2d::UserDefault functionality.

```
UserPref::ReadFromUserDefault() {
  _mx_username = cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance()->getStringForKey("mx_username", "");
}
```

Is it possible to get cocos2d::UserDefault to point to a fake XML file of my own creation for the purposes of unit testing my class?

Thanks!
GCB

Comment: The best way to read an XML file is to use a library that provides the functionality.  Search the internet for something like "c++ XML library".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - So just create an entirely different "Read" function that access the XML file instead of the UserDefault just for testing purposes?

Comment: Sorry, but the `cocos2d` API is beyond my scope. :-(

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - No worries, I appreciate the comments! :-)